# What is the purpose of this disk over a Samtec connector?

Tags: pcb-design, model

With beautification in mind I decided to attach 3D-STEP models to elements on my PCB.

One of them is a connector from Samtec. They do provide a STEP models for a download, but it was immediately suspicious to me, that the preview had this weird disc over the connector. At that moment I thought it was some kind of glitch and proceeded downloading STEP model regardless.

See the image below:
[image: Connector preview]

Attaching the downloaded STEP model I was surprised by this disc again. Turns out, it was also exported into STEP model along with the connector. Unfortunately, this serves bad for the purpose of "beautification" :)

Questions are:

- What is the purpose of this disk?
- Is there any way to download a STEP model of Samtec connector without this disk?

For a reference, the connector is [QSH-030-01-F-D-A-K](https://www.samtec.com/products/qsh-030-01-f-d-a-k)

Comment: Now that you know what it is, their website lets you disable the "pick-n-place" pad when generating the model :)

Comment: @crasic Really? I couldn't find anything, that disables it. It has a listbox of download options and "Download" button.

Comment: To do that, you need to visit the page with the generic series,  not with the specific part number; check out https://www.samtec.com/products/qsh

Comment: @VladimirCravero That was already obvious after Mast's answer.

Comment: Now that you have accepted it, and it is on the top of the list, it is obvious to me as well :).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This hasn't been explicitly mentioned yet, but you got a disc because you asked for one.

It's a Polyimide film pad, and specified by the last code in your part: -K. The purpose of this pad is so the vacuum pick-and-place machine has something to hold the component on. It needs a flat surface big enough for the vacuum head, as already shown by [Jeroen3](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501885/53015) and [DKNguyen](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/501879/53015). For manual manufacturing, you don't need the film pad. But some automated lines can't pick up the parts if there's no flat surface provided.

QSH-030-01-F-D-A-K has the pad, QSH-030-01-F-D-A does not.

030-01 says how many positions and the lead style. The other codes:

- -F: 3u plating
- -D: double rows
- -A: alignment pins
- -K: Polyimide film pad

See the [QSH configurator](https://www.samtec.com/products/qsh). Find your new, padless STP files there too.

[image: QSH-030-01-F-D-A]

Polyimide (also known under the brandname Kapton) is stable for a wide temperature range and a good electrical isolator, making it ideal for this purpose.

Comment: Just what I was about to say. I love the Samtec part configuration abilities.

Comment: Aha! This answer adds some additional info on top of what the higher-rated ones have. +1!

Comment: So the answer is "you got a disc because you asked for one". Now I feel stupid :( That must have been a punishment for blindly copying the connector from an evaluation board.

Answer (score 45):

That orange disk represents a pick-and-place sticker—it provides something for the pick-and-place machine's vacuum head to grab onto. Without this, you'd have to assemble the connector by hand.

Here is an example photo of a similar Samtec SS4 with the vacuum pick and place sticker in place:

[image]

Answer (score 21):

It is a place for the pick-and-place machine's vacuum head to grab onto.

[image]

Taken from [Adafruit](https://blog.adafruit.com/2013/05/20/neoden-tm240a-pick-and-place-machine-manufacturing-manufacturingmonday/)

Comment: It really sucks

Comment: It's vacuum. There's nothing to it.

Comment: @Transistor: But you still have to pump vacuum into the chamber (yes, operators in a [sugar refinery](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sugar_refinery) actually used jargon like that)

Comment: @PeterMortensen Well...we have hole flow so...........

Answer (score 8):

The polyamide pick and place disk is part of the assembly as defined.

If you have a 3D CAD program that uses of one of the very many supported formats you can simply open the file and delete the disk, then save it as an AP214 .stp file.

[image]

Otherwise you are at the mercy of whoever is creating these files and the options they happen to offer.

You can probably find a demo or free version of one of the supported pieces of software.